# noise remains after applying median filter

Tags: image-processing, filters, python

So I'm apply the median filter to an image, but at the output, there's blue semi-dots appearing. What are they?

This is the output

[image]

And the python code for anyone interested

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import median_filter
from matplotlib.pylab import imread, imshow, subplot, title, show, get_cmap

img = imread('images/speckle.gif')
new = median_filter(img, 3)

subplot(121); imshow(img, cmap=get_cmap('gray'));
title('The original')
subplot(122); imshow(new, cmap=get_cmap('gray'));
title('Filtered with the median_filter')

show()
```

Comment: Because that over/underflow on calculation

Comment: I dont know what that means

Comment: It means that under/overflows are happen when if you are on calculate without prevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the image to gray scale before applying the median filter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting this image to gray and then apply median filter, an alternative is to use the vector median filter. In this context, a vector median filter considers each pixel as a 3D-vector composed by R, G, and B channel intensities, and finds a median w.r.t. to this vector instead one median for each channel.

Comment: I would prefer this to first converting the image to gray. But I don't know how to implement it in python. Any pointers?